# Regular submanifold vs. submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I´ve a question involving two definitions:

For $M$ a differential manifold, is $R \subset M$ a ***submanifold*** if the inclusion $i : R \longrightarrow M$ is an immersion (that is, is differentiable with $\operatorname{rank}(i) = \dim M$).

Also, $R \subset M$ a ***regular submanifold*** if the inclusion $i : R \longrightarrow M$ is an immersion and also $i : R \longrightarrow i(R) \subset M$ is an homeomorphism.

Thanks.

**Note:** But any inclusion $i : R \to i(R) \subset M$ is an homeomorphism, yeah? So, any submanifold is a regular manifold.

Answer (score 0):

The second definition is stronger than the first one. Sometimes, such a manifold is called ***embedded*** submanifold. It means that the submanifold topology on it is the same as the subspace topology.

Comment: Yeah, but if any inclusion over its image is an homeomorphism, you´ve ever that any submanifold is a regular manifold, yeah?

Comment: Yes, but you work in the smooth category.

Comment: Can you detail your answer, please? :)    Any submanifold (regular or not) has the same topology than the other one $M$, no?

Comment: You have to say which topology you consider on $i(R)$. You can induce on it a topology such that $i$ is an homemorphism but this topology is not necessarily the subsapve topology as a subset of $M$.